# Converting a JSON strings list to a JSON array in Python

Tags: python, json

Having this list with two `JSON strings` on it:

```
myJSONStringList = ['{"user": "testuser", "data": {"version": 1, "timestamp": "2018-04-03T09:23:43.388Z"}, "group": "33"}',
'{"user": "otheruser", "data": {"version": 2, "timestamp": "2018-04-03T09:23:43.360Z", }, "group": "44"}']
```

How can I convert this to a JSON array? This is my desired output:

```
[{"user": "testuser", "data": {"version": 1, "timestamp": "2018-04-03T09:23:43.388Z"}, "group": "33"}, 
{"user": "otheruser", "data": {"version": 2, "timestamp": "2018-04-03T09:23:43.360Z", }, "group": "44"}]
```

I know I can do a dirty solution by just doing `myJSONStringList.replace("'", "")`, but is there any pythonic solution to this by using, for example, the `json` module?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

decode JSON strings into dicts and put them in a list, last, convert the list to JSON

```
json_list = []
json_list.append(json.loads(JSON_STRING))
json.dumps(json_list)
```

or more pythonic syntax

```
output_list = json.dumps([json.loads(JSON_STRING) for JSON_STRING in JSON_STRING_LIST])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `json.dumps` before `json.loads` to convert your data to dictionary object This also helps prevent `valueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes`.

**Ex:**

```
import json
myJSONStringList = ['{"user": "testuser", "data": {"version": 1, "timestamp": "2018-04-03T09:23:43.388Z"}, "group": "33"}',
'{"user": "otheruser", "data": {"version": 2, "timestamp": "2018-04-03T09:23:43.360Z", }, "group": "44"}']

print([json.loads(json.dumps(i)) for i in myJSONStringList])
```

**Output:**

```
[u'{"user": "testuser", "data": {"version": 1, "timestamp": "2018-04-03T09:23:43.388Z"}, "group": "33"}', u'{"user": "otheruser", "data": {"version": 2, "timestamp": "2018-04-03T09:23:43.360Z", }, "group": "44"}']
```